# Is there a way to improve the label of a bucket created by cut?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I used `pd.cut` to bin my data, but when I plot it the label looks bad. Is there a way to change that?

```
df["rel"].plot(kind="bar", ax=ax[0, 0])
ax[0, 0].set(xlabel="Weight Bucket", ylabel="Relative Frequency (%)")
ax[0, 0].tick_params(axis="x", labelrotation=20)
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

Preferably I would like it to look like `2.5-3.8`, `3.8-5.0`, ...

Comment: you can pass whatever labels you want directly to `pandas.cut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the index:

```
df.index = [f'{x.left:.1f}-{x.right:.1f}' for x in df.index]

# then plot
df["rel"].plot(kind="bar", ax=ax[0, 0])
```

If you don't want to modify your dataframe, bar against the formatted index:

```
ax[0,0].bar([f'{x.left:.1f}-{x.right:.1f}' for x in df.index], df['rel'])
```